# To run perl script every 5 minutes, and exit properly

Tags: perl

I have a script which I need to run every 5 minutes till the time I have my file in a directory on which my script is based. That file will be moved automatically and that time I want my script to exit too. Also I do not want to schedule it with cron as this would be running along with some other process only, and I want this script to run only till the time the particular file is present in directory and exit once the file isnt there.

I tried using sleep in while loop but then the script is writing nothing to OUTLOG, which is log file for the script and also if the file on which script is based isnt present, it is going for forever sleep but not exiting.

```
while (1) {
    sleep 300;

    <Calling subroutine check>
    }

    sub check {
    #check for a file in a specified directory
    # print OUTLOG statements in all script which are not working with WHILE LOOP.
    #do further processing if file is present
    #calls sub sendemail
    }

    sub sendemail {
    #sends mail
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide actual code in a form of a working example. What you provided isn't enough to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: that would be too large. Please let me know where specifically it is not understood so I can make you clear.

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you provided pseudo code, so how do you expect us to help? Aside from doing it for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $done=0; # Will be 1 if we are done.
my $infile='/path/to/myfile.txt';
while ($done==0)
  {
  sleep 300; # Wait 5 minutes
  if (-e $infile) # See if file exists
    {
    # Do something with file then delete it. 
    unlink $infile or die "ERROR: Could not delete $infile"; # Delete file.
    $done=1; # Now exit loop and program.
    }
  } # while
exit;
```

Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Wow, what's with the downvotes? Are we discouraging visual learners now? Is this site only about specific learning types excluding others? We were all beginners at one time having no clue how to do X.

Comment: You could also do the same thing by replacing the `$done=1` statement with a [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) statement in a `while(1)` loop.

Comment: @oldtechaa: good idea for teaching OP about the "last" statement. "last" exits the loop also. "last" also exits for loops.

Comment: @oldtechaa Thanks Bulrush and oldtechaa. Using "last" concept wokred. In the if condition when the file is found I did all the work and put the last in else look when while isnt found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't exit because you never told Perl to exit the loop.

```
sub wait_for_file {
   my ($qfn) = @_;
   while (1) {
      last if -e $qfn;
      sleep 300;
   }
}

{
   my $qfn = ...;
   wait_for_file($qfn);
   ... do stuff ...
}
```